# How to display two dynamic names within one url using laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

The following code:

```
{{url('/'.$subjecttype->name)}}
```

is the name 'garden' wrapped up in a url. This gives me localhost/garden with obviously garden as the dynamic name. With my routes setup like so:

```
Route::get('/{subject}/', array( 'as' => 'subject', 'uses' => 
'SubjectController@getsubject'));
```

**The question is how would I setup two dynamic names within one route?** For example

localhost/garden/12

so i would want my route to look something like this

`Route::get('/{subject}/{id}/', array( 'as' => 'subjectid', 'uses' => 'SubjectController@getsubjectid'));`

**but more importantly what would it look like in my view?** so that I have the of my garden header wrapped up in a url that looks like this:

'gardening tips for beginners' which is `{{$subjecttype->title}}`

below is my very poor attempt at what i want but i hope you get the picture.

`{{url('/$subjecttype->name/$subjecttype->id/'.$subjecttype->title)}}`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your route:

```
Route::get(
    '/{subject}/{id}/',
    array(
        'as' => 'subjectid',
        'uses' => 'SubjectController@getsubjectid'
    )
);
```

you can generate the URL with the following code:

```
$url = URL::route(
    'subjectid',
    array(
        'subject' => $subjecttype->name,
        'id' => $subjecttype->id
    )
);
```

or, if you prefer to use the helper functions:

```
$url = route(
    'subjectid',
    array(
        'subject' => $subjecttype->name,
        'id' => $subjecttype->id
    )
);
```

That's going to give you a URL like `http://example.com/subjectname/42`. If you want to add another parameter like the title at the end of the URL, you'll need to add another parameter to your route definition. If you don't you're going to get 404 errors because no route will match the URL.

Comment: thanks @Kryten and how would I use this url in the view? for axample `{{url('/$subjecttype->name/$subjecttype->id/'.$subjecttype->title)}}`

Comment: Rather than using the `url()` function, I'd use the `route()` function. The difference is that the `route()` function works with route **names**. This allows you to abstract away from concrete URLs - later on, you can change the URL if you need to and your code will still work. Simply use the `route()` function like in my example in your blade template.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of my question using the 'gardening tips for beginners' example:

`<a href="{{ URL::to(action('SubjectController@getsubjectid', array($subjecttype->title, $subjecttype->id)))}}">gardening tips for beginners</a>`